# Partition size issue

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, storage, fdisk

I have a server with 4TB HDD, however, there is a strange issue where it seems like main partition is only 200 GB, which shouldn't be the case.

if I check with `lsblk -a` I get:

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0  99.4M  1 loop /snap/core/11993
loop1                       7:1    0 110.5M  1 loop /snap/core/12603
loop2                       7:2    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2253
loop3                       7:3    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2284
loop4                       7:4    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1270
loop5                       7:5    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1328
loop6                       7:6    0  67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21803
loop7                       7:7    0  67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835
loop8                       7:8    0  43.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14295
loop9                       7:9    0  43.4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14549
loop10                      7:10   0         0 loop 
sda                         8:0    0   3.7T  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   3.7T  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   200G  0 lvm  /
```

What I understand means that HDD is 3.7TB, however the actual partition is 200GB?

Then I tried `fdisk -l` which shows for SDA :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA HDWD240 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 783FCAA1-FFDE-43BF-9EA8-61D5CCADE835

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624    3147775    2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  3147776 7814033407 7810885632  3.7T Linux filesystem
```

Showing that **sda3** is actually 3.7TB.

Last command I tried is `df -h` which shows 200gb again:

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              764M  2.6M  761M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  196G   13G  174G   7% /
tmpfs                              3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2253
/dev/loop0                         100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11993
/dev/loop3                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop1                         111M  111M     0 100% /snap/core/12603
/dev/loop4                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1270
/dev/loop5                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1328
/dev/loop7                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21835
/dev/loop6                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21803
/dev/loop8                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14295
/dev/loop9                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14549
/dev/sda2                          976M  402M  507M  45% /boot
/dev/sda1                          511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              764M     0  764M   0% /run/user/0
```

Can someone please help me make sense of this? If the partition is 200 GB I need to create a new one from the remaining 3.5TB and map it onto /Shares/ , but with Fdisk showing partition being the full size I am at a loss.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

so I figured out it's the LVM.
To extend it I used:

```
lvextend -l +902277 /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```

following [this tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/#:%7E:text=We%20can%20extend%20using%20GB,available%20Physical%20Extend%20size%20run.&text=There%20are%204607%20free%20PE%20available%20%3D%2018GB%20Free%20space%20available.&text=For%20extending%20Logical%20volumes%20we,to%20unmount%20the%20file%2Dsystem.).